# Redux connected React component not updating on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Whenever my 'COLLEGE_ADDED' action is dispatched I can see the state changes in the reducer. However the update related lifecycle methods on the CollegeSearchList component and it's children aren't being called. These components aren't re-rendering presumably because of this.

I have read the docs about not mutating state and I don't think I am. Complete code can be found here https://github.com/tlatkinson/react-search-widget.

components/search/college/CollegeSearchList.js

```
class CollegeSearchList extends Component {
    componentWillUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log(nextProps.searchItems);
        console.log(nextState);
        return true;
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <SearchList searchItems={this.props.searchItems} SearchListItem={CollegeSearchListItem} />
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, {id}) => {
    return {
        searchItems: getSearchResultsById(state.searchState, id),
        SearchListItem: CollegeSearchListItem,
    }
};

CollegeSearchList = connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(CollegeSearchList);
```

reducers/search.js

```
const searchReducer = (searchState = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'COLLEGE_SEARCH':
            return mergeData(searchState, action, 'college', 'phrase');
        case 'COLLEGE_SEARCH_SUCCESS':
            return mergeData(searchState, action, 'college', 'searchResults');
        case 'COLLEGE_ADDED':
            return updateCollegeAdded(searchState, action.collegeId, true);
        case 'COLLEGE_REMOVED':
            return updateCollegeAdded(searchState, action.collegeId, false);
        default:
            return searchState;
    }
};

export default searchReducer

const updateCollegeAdded = (searchState, collegeId, added) => {
    const newState = {...searchState};

    for (let id of Object.keys(newState)) {
        const searchComponent = searchState[id];

        if(searchComponent.searchType === 'college') {
            searchComponent.searchResults.forEach(searchResult => {
                if(searchResult.id === collegeId) {
                    searchResult.added = added;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    return newState;
};

const mergeData = (data, action, searchType, propertyModified) => {
    return {
        ...data,
        [action.id]: {
            searchType,
            ...data[action.id],
            [propertyModified]: action[propertyModified],
        }
    };
};
```

actions/index.js

```
export const addRemoveCollege = (collegeId, collegeName, addToList) => (dispatch) => {
    if (addToList) {
        api.addToCollegeList(collegeId)
            .then(() => {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'COLLEGE_ADDED',
                    collegeId,
                    collegeName,
                });
            })
    } else {
        api.removeFromCollegeList(collegeId)
            .then(() => {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'COLLEGE_REMOVED',
                    collegeId,
                    collegeName,
                });
            })
    }
};
```

Comment: In configureStore you've added rootReducer. You have no other reducer, so just import searchReducer from search.js. At least that's what I think is the problem. Try that.

Comment: I'm combining the searchReducer into the main reducer in reducer/index.js. Other search actions work. They wouldn't work if they couldn't see the search reducer?

Comment: Are you using combineReducer to do that? If so I can't see that in the repo

Comment: Sorry my bad, saw that. Let me check

Comment: Please also be aware that connect does a shallow compare, so if the new props are not different from the old one, component will not re-render. So even if state changes, connect fires a mapStateToProps, and then does a comparison and after that decides whether to re-render.

Comment: That's good info and sounds like it could be my problem. To quickly test that I added a boolean "modified" property to the top level object of my search state / reducer. I inverted this field every time an action was dispatched and there is still no change. Would there be anything else I need to do?